# How to get Min/Max value of Simulink inport block in Matlab programatically?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to get Min/Max value of the inport block parameters below and use it in a matlab script.

We need these values to use them later in the code.

[image: block parameters inport block window]

I tried to use get_param function but it did not work. It returns only the prompt : the text over the value I want ie "Minimum:" / "Maximum:".

But I want the value and not the text.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have you model loaded in memory (programmatically is load_system('modelName'), then:

```
min=get_param('path2InportBlock','OutMin');
max=get_param('path2InportBlock','OutMax');
```

Yes you can get all the inport blocks paths programamtically with:

```
getfullname(find_system('modelName', 'FindAll', 'on', 'BlockType', 'Inport');
```